# How to Broadcast UDP packs to Specific IPs connected to LAN only

Tags: sockets, delphi, udp

Can it be done in XE7+ to Broadcast the UDP packets to specific machines/IPs?

For example, I have 10 machine in LAN. Server Broadcasted to all 10 machines. Two machines accepted the packets (clients) and Server then tool its details and keep it in DB. Now these machines are down and up again. Server again Broadcasted the UDP packets but this time to only 8 machines/IPs; and two active machines who were already hand-shaked are not sent these packets. In this process we keep on adding the machine/IPs in our DB till the time all the machines/IPs are added. Once all are added then no UDP packets is sent by the Server. It would become responsibility of the machine to send data packets once it is up.

**Update:**

I need only suggestion and guidance. Rest would be taken care by me like coding, threading etc.

Comment: SO is not actually a CanIHazCodez site, try one of those CodersForHire sites.

Comment: What library are you using for communication? What platform(s)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What specific guidance you need? And how it relates to `[delphi]`? Again, please be specific.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, a UDP broadcast cannot target a specific peer IP, only a network subnet.  If you target a specific IP, it is not a broadcast anymore, you are just doing direct peer-to-peer communication normally.

For what you are attempting, you will have to broadcast across the subnet each time so you can discover new machines, and just ignore responses from any machines you already know about.